# Scala/akka Pattern Matching a Sequence of Futures pipelined to a actor message

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka, actor, future

Ok I'm trying to create a **unit of work** of web requests and pipe it to an actor when it's done. I don't understand the matching ins and outs well enough yet and i'm losing hair trying to come up with a way to do the match.

I've got a catch-all style of a match with `case _ : Seq[_]` how would I go about **1)** getting a proper case class matcher, in this case `Seq[SubcategoryResponse]` and **2)** how would do I get a handle to it inside the match body ?

```
val next_batch = Future.traverse(result.urls.get)(u => {
      val F = System.requester ? makeGetRequest(Root(),u.data)
      val F1 = F.map(f=> SubcategoryResponse(f.asInstanceOf[HttpResponse],u.payload.get,level+1))
      F1
    })
val res = Await result(next_batch, 20.seconds)
println(res.getClass)
res match {
  case _ : Seq[_] => {
    println("boom")
  }
}
```

**edit: Bingo**

Simple syntax :( -> `m : Seq[SubcategoryResponse]`. The compiler warning doesn't make me feel very comfortable though. **So my new question is, what does type erasure mean in this context. Do i need to take that warning seriously ? If so, how do I get around it ?**

```
[warn] /Users/hassan/code/scala/extractor/HonCrawler.scala:139: non-variable type argument HonCategoryBootstrap.this.SubcategoryResponse in type pattern Seq[HonCategoryBootstrap.this.SubcategoryResponse] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]     case m : Seq[SubcategoryResponse] => {
[warn]              ^
[warn] one warning found
```

Comment: Type erasure means that Scala can't distinguish between Seq[SubcategoryResponse] and Seq[AnythingElse] in this context. For more information [see this article](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/01/overcoming-type-erasure-in-matching-1.html).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sending `Seq`s as messages, wrap the `Seq` in another class.  For example:

```
case class SubcategoryResponses(responses: Seq[SubcategoryResponse])
```

Then you can match on the case class:

```
res match {
  case SubcategoryResponses(responses) =>
```